# Loading MySql in terminal Window of MAC throws error "not a valid identifier"

Tags: mysql, macos, command

After installing & starting MySQL on Mac, i can not make terminal recognise mysql though I type in the following code to make system know where its saved:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ . ~/.bash_profile

-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Would appreciate on what am I missing,

Comment: Looks like you might be using a `tick` somethere `\`` instead of a `single quote` `'`

Comment: Thanks, it worked out well, just followed a video on youtube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcpHkYfWarM", everything is sorted out now and I am good to go :)